# How to close dynamically created Tab in Lightning

Tags: create-component

On click of a button Tab is created dynamically, using attribute "endIconName":"utility:close", close icon placed in the tab. how to close this tab.

```
 $A.createComponent("lightning:tab", {
    "label": "New Tab",        
    "endIconName":"utility:close",

}, function (newComponent, status, error) {
    if (status === "SUCCESS") {
        newComponent.set("v.body", btnCmp);
        tabCmp = newComponent; 
        tablst.push(tabCmp);                        
    } else {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you try with `component.destroy()`, if the component is not stored any facets or  `v.body`

Comment: how to make the close Icon clickable

Comment: Looking at the documentation it doesn't seem you have a way to bind the close action from the tab end icon (endIconName). I would suggest a global button outside of the created component that reads something like "Remove active tab" and call the destroy after determining which one is open.